# How to add product and product category in quotation pivot list in below list like sale analysis in odoo 11?

Tags: python-3.x, odoo, odoo-11

[in sale analysis on total two list product and product category there. same things I want to add in quotation pivot table how can I add?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That is not really possible, because the BI (Business Intelligence) reports (you called it "sale analysis" in your question) are actually transformed data with sales order LINES as base. And the pivot of sales order are based on sales order. You don't have product and product category information, because you have a one to many relation to order lines where this information is belonging to. It's only working the other way around (lines information -> order information).

So the solution is probably extending sale analysis (i think the model is `sale.report`) with every other thing you're missing there instead of changing the pivot of sales orders.